# TFS 'Get Latest' does not really get latest

Tags: tfs

I checked in a changeset adding ~10 media files to my TFS branch. However, upon successive calls to 'Get Latest' by the rest of the people on the branch, none of them were able to actually get the files until they chose 'Get Specific Version' from Source Control Explorer, and checked both boxes.

It should be noted that these media files were in the same folder as the project they belonged to; however they are *not* part of the project/solution (you can't see them from Solution Explorer in Visual Studio).

Here are my two ideas of what (may) have been the issue:

- They chose to 'Get Latest' from the Solution Explorer rather than the Source Control Explorer; updating their workspace version but not actually downloading the files.
- Adding these files somehow did not count as a change.

I realize that it is difficult to try and answer a question with such limited information, but I am curious as to why they weren't the able to get the new media files.

Also, how could problems like this be avoided in the future (best practices)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding files will always count as a change.

I would assume that your first idea is what's happening.  Get Latest from the solution explorer only updates those files in the solution tree.  If the files are part of the solution, you may want to consider adding them as content items so they are updated appropriately.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! It looks like that is the issue. I guess I will have to tell the team to get the latest via Source Control Explorer from now on; as adding the media as resources to the solution is impractical at best in our case.

Comment: Just curious why it is impracitcal.  Add it to a folder, and set the BuildAction (under properties) to "none".  Then it should be included in the project, but not included in the build.

Comment: We are talking hundreds of thousands of media files, totaling about 39 Gb of space. Also; the media needs to be swapable for localization and build needs.

Comment: Yikes.  Sounds like a fun project, though.

Comment: I always recommend for developers to use either tf.exe or Source Control Explorer for doing get latest operations.